# What to do when the part datasheet gives the SMD part dimensions but nothing related to PCB footprint dimensions?

Tags: altium

This is from datasheet of Panasonic SMD resistor ERJ-8ENF3000V. The datasheet can be found [here](https://industrial.panasonic.com/cdbs/www-data/pdf/RDA0000/AOA0000C304.pdf).

The page 4 of the datsheet shows this:

[image]

While the part physical dimensions are given, the actual SMD pad dimenions are not given. Since I need to create a PCB footprint for this part, what do I do now?

What is the point of giving all these numbers but nothing for the SMD pad dimensions?

Comment: The actual pad dimensions vary depending on a number of factors like how the board is going to be assembled. There are IPC standards that will give guidance.

Comment: Just FYI, that datasheet says that the ERJ8E resistors are "not recommended for new designs", which is why they are greyed out.

Comment: @ Kartman, what in the world is an IPC standard? I will have to Google that.

Comment: @Quantum0xE7 IPC-7351 is the standard you're after, if you want to know what rules are used by the footprint "wizards", including wizards included in KiCad, etc.

Comment: The world of IPC has been opemned up to be. It is sad that the IPC-7351 is not available for free.

Answer (score 3):

Well, in this case, it is 3.2 mm long by 1.6 mm wide. So it is a "3216" metric chip resistor. Just use the footprint from some other 3216 (metric) chip resistor. It is a standard size. Also known as "1206" because it is about 0.12 by 0.06 inches.

Comment: I see. Actually what I found is that of the several "1206" LEDs, there were small differences in the different recommended footprints. Based on this, I assume that any "1206" component be it resistor, capacitor or inductor, will also have small differences in how the PCB pads should be created.

Comment: @Quantum0xE7 the LED's may be different from the resistors and from the caps. The resistors will have very similar dimensions to each other and be interchangeable. You can study the dimensions on the actual component and compare them with other chip resistors to see how they compare. But I think any generic 1206 resistor footprint will probably work.